# Azure search term matching issue

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm using the English.Lucene analyzer, searching for the term 'rocking chairs' correctly returns results such as
rocking chair

but does not return results such as
rocker

What can I do to tune the index so that it returns these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Synonym map https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms and map rocking to rocker so that results with rocker are also returned.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jdresc, mentioned synonym maps are a great option, however, I also recommend taking a look at the /analyze api to see how this analyzer (and other such as Microsoft English analyzer) tokenizes this word to see if it may be more appropriate for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer

Comment: Thanks I did see this analyzer.  While it is helpful, I went with synonym maps.  I can see how the analyzer would be helpful in identifying shortfalls, and places where I'd need to create a synonym map.  Because the tokenization isn't quite right on a particular analyzer.  It is a bit cumbersome to try out many different analyzers and terms with the hopes of maybe landing on one that works for you